# Cannot link address sanitizer in XCode 12

Tags: c++, xcode, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to build C++ project in xcode with asan. At linking step build fails with error:

```
Undefined symbol: ___asan_version_mismatch_check_apple_clang_1200
```

I checked the box in "Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme>Address Sanitizer" and added linker flag in "Other linking options": "-fsanitize=address".

From log I can see that it runs ld command with -fsanitize=address flag.

However, with all these steps it still doesn't work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: No clue about xcode, but possibly you are missing some libraries. Make sure they are installed.

Comment: What if you compile from the prompt: `clang++ -o foo source.cpp -fsanitize=address` - same issue?

Comment: `clang++ -o foo source.cpp -fsanitize=address` works fine. And it actually compiles with asan.

Comment: @ArialPilisov My guess is then that Xcode isn't setup properly so that it links with the wrong asan library.

Comment: Are there any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: @ArialPilisov No, sorry, I have no clue about Xcode myself. Perhaps there's a tutorial about how to set it up properly? One would think that if you point out the compiler you'd like to use (do `which clang++` from the prompt and use that path in Xcode) it would use the proper libraries.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't stuff things like that into Other linking options - Xcode is likely to get confused (and, I believe, the compiler needs to know too).

Instead, edit your Scheme (or create a new one) to enable Address Sanitizer in the Diagnostics tab, as per the following screenshot:

[image]

This is what I do and it works fine (and ASAN is magic!).

Comment: That's what I tried, but unfortunately It didn't work. It produces the mentioned error.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I re-read your post and saw that.  I'd remove that flag though.  I guess, then, that the thing to do is to delete Xcode from your Applications folder and install it again from the App Store.  I'm on 13.4 now, maybe that makes a difference.  Apple are always breaking stuff...

Comment: Also, you could blow away all your intermediate and build products and rebuild, Xcode's build system is not exactly 100% reliable.